# Collapse XML to elements in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio and most other editors you can collapse XML to tag / element level. Is there any way to do the same in Visual Studio code or is this feature still to come?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<s>This is currently not possible but we plan to provide this feature in the future. You can suggest new features like this from our [User Voice page](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code). You can find your suggestion [there](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7752321-add-code-folding-support).</s>

**Update for our VS Code 1.0 release:**

Code folding has been implemented now!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Benjamin - adding code folding would be great! If I have any other suggestions I'll add them on the user voice page.

Comment: Not yet, but planned for our next release.

Comment: This is working now. You don't see the Plus and Minus icons automatically like you do in Visual Studio. Instead, just hover in the blank space to the right of the line number and they will show up. You can also use the keyboard shortcuts. See https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf

Comment: what is the shortcut? I cannot find it in the command palette (CTRL+SHIFT+P) also

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+Num</kbd> to fold level `Num`, where `Num = 0-9`;
<kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd> to unfold all
(palette shows you the shortcuts)

Comment: Doesn't work except `Ctrl+K Ctrl+0` and `Ctrl+K Ctrl+J`.

Comment: @Marcel It's not very intuitive. Use ctrl-k, ctrl-j to reset, then you can use other numbers such as ctrl-k, ctrl-4. It appears you can't jump from level 3 to level 4 though without going through ctrl-k,ctrl-j first.

Answer (score 7):

Select the node you want to collapse, Ctrl + Shift + [

Answer (score 4):

XML node folding is available as part of [XML](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-xml), the extension built by Red Hat for VS Code.